# Not able to connect/call services of other nodes Moleculer NodeJs

Tags: node.js, moleculer

I have created 2 nodes for moleculer using

```
npm init project project_name
```

I have added a service users.list in project one which gives list of all users which is working fine also i exposed its api.
But issue is, when i run the other node project2, and in action of service i call user.list it shows SERVICE_NOT_FOUNT. However it is calling its own functions but not the functions of other nodes

> I want to connect different nodes so that i can call services of one node in other, i don't know what i am missing or doing wrong, because i followed documentation of moleculer which says it should work like that, but its not working

I am using REDIS as transporter.
Here is code for action

```
welcome: {
            params: {
                name: "string"
            },
            async handler(ctx) {
                var tmp = await ctx.call("users.list",{});

                return `Welcome, ${tmp}`;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using namespaces? Both nodes should use the same namespace & Redis transporter.

Comment: i have not added any namespace, it is empty on both the nodes

Comment: please include console messages from both nodes.